# vertical menu bar

Tags: menus

I am trying to generate a menu using wp_nav_menu.I am stuck this . My expected output is this:
                    
                    
                          
                            Go!

```
                <a href="index.html" class="list-group-item">
                    Home
                </a>
                <a href="about.html" class="list-group-item">About us</a>
                <a href="service.html" class="list-group-item">Services</a>
                <a href="allumi.html" class="list-group-item">Allumi</a>
            </div>
```

And i am using this code to aquire this:

```
   'Primary Menu', 'menu_class' => 'list-group-item','items_wrap'=>'%3$s' ]); ?>
```

i am not getting the expected result.can anyone help me?

Comment: it will add menu class to ul item. not to a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a filter in your functions.php file:

```
function mytheme_nav_menu_css_class($classes, $item, $args) {
  if($args->theme_location == 'secondary') {
    $classes[] = 'your-class-name';
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class','mytheme_nav_menu_css_class');
```

Or if you go to your WP Admin, click Appearance -> Menus and then click the tab at the top "Screen Options", you can tick `CSS Classes` which will enable you to add a class to each list item in your menu.

See [this article](http://sdtuts.com/wordpress-add-custom-class-in-wp_nav_menu-links/) for details.